# Injecting ApplicationContext into a Micronaut bean on creation

Tags: micronaut

I am attempting to inject Micronaut's ApplicationContext into a bean when it is created in order to use it to dynamically find another bean. Essentially what I am trying to make happen is pass a string to the bean's constructor to use as the name in Micronaut's appContext.getBean() method using Qualifiers.byName(name) in order to actually find the correct bean. I do not believe the @Named annotation applies here as I need to be able to provide the name dynamically instead of having a hard coded value

I tried passing the name into the constructor, setting it as a private variable within the class, then using @Inject for the applicationcontext and finding the bean I need in a method annotated with @PostConstruct, however I got a Null exception as the ApplicationContext had not yet been injected when the @PostConstruct method was executed. At the moment I have it working by using constructor injection for the ApplicationContext then making a call to another method after creating the object and passing the name to that method, however I am certain there is a smoother, more efficient way for this to be done, I just cannot figure out what that would be

EDIT for what ive tried so far, basic examples with different method/variable names (this.bean has been properly declared each time just not added to this post):

Injecting application context and using PostConstruct

```
@Inject
ApplicationContext appcontext

private String name;

public some_class(String name){
     this.name = name;
}

@PostConstruct
public void findBean(){
     this.bean = appContext.getBean(BeanClass.class, Qualifiers.byName(name))
}
```

@Inject

```
@Inject 
private ApplicationContext appContext;

public some_class(String name){
     this.bean = appContext.getBean(BeanClass.class, Qualifiers.byName(name))
}
```

Constructor Injection with separate method (Currently in use)

```
private ApplicationContext appContext;

public some_class(ApplicationContext appContext){
     this.appContext = appContext;
}

public void set_bean(String name){
     this.bean = appContext.getBean(BeanClass.class, Qualifiers.byName(name))
}
```

EDIT (Solution):
After more thought and assistance from others, the solution I will be using for this project is using the named annotation to get the bean and then passing the bean to the constructor as opposed to passing the name.

```
public void some_func(@Named("BEANNAME") BeanType bean){
      beanConstructor(bean);
}

public beanConstructor(BeanType bean){
      this.bean = bean;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to inject the `ApplicationContext` or how to deal with the bean name (those are 2 separate questions with separate answers)?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown primarily asking how to inject application context specifically either within the constructor (either without using constructor injection, or by being able to do constructor injection while still passing a separate value such as function void some_func(String name, ApplicationContext)) or prior to a post construct method

Comment: "Essentially what I am trying to make happen is pass a string to the bean's constructor to use as the name in Micronaut's appContext.getBean()" - Is there an unexpressed requirement to have the bean name injected, or would it be sufficient to have the bean of that name injected instead?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I am trying to make it so the bean name can be dynamically provided as opposed to a hard coded value. For example instead of just using the named annotation for Named("Some Bean") I want to be able to have it inject Some Bean or any other bean depending on the name that is passed to it. Is the Named annotation able to work with variable names? I thought it had to be a hardcoded/static value